# Display form variable on other page with perhaps a session?

Tags: php, forms, validation, post

Purpose of my code is:
- Validate the form and check for empty fields
- Send e-mail to admin
- Add data to Mysql database
- Show data on result.php

Currently im experiencing problems with showing my data on result.php

quiz.php

```
 <?php

require_once("php/db.php");                 /* Database Class */
require_once('php/utils/is_email.php');     /* Email Validation Script */


$contact = new Contact();


/* Class Contact */
class Contact
{
        private $db;                        /* the database obj */

        //we have to init $errors array, as otherwise form will produce errors on missing array entry
        private $errors = array(            /* holds error messages */
                'aanhef' => '',
                'contactpersoon' => '',
                'bedrijfsnaam' => '',
                'email' => '',
                'telefoon' => '',
                'vraag1_antwoorden' => '',
                'vraag2_antwoorden' => ''
        );

        private $has_errors;                /* number of errors in submitted form */

        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->db = new DB();
                if (!empty($_POST['newcontact'])) {
                        $this->processNewMessage();
                }
        }
        public function processNewMessage()
        {
                $aanhef             = $_POST['aanhef'];
                $contactpersoon     = $_POST['contactpersoon'];
                $bedrijfsnaam       = $_POST['bedrijfsnaam'];
                $telefoon           = $_POST['telefoon'];
                $email              = $_POST['email'];
                $vraag1_antwoorden  = $_POST['vraag1_antwoorden'];
                $vraag2_antwoorden  = $_POST['vraag2_antwoorden'];

                /* Server Side Data Validation */
                if (empty($aanhef)) {
                        $this->setError('aanhef', 'Vul uw aanhef in');
                }

                if (empty($contactpersoon)) {
                        $this->setError('contactpersoon', 'Vul uw contactpersoon in');
                }

                if (empty($bedrijfsnaam)) {
                        $this->setError('bedrijfsnaam', 'Vul uw bedrijfsnaam in');
                }

                if (empty($telefoon)) {
                        $this->setError('telefoon', 'Vul uw telefoon in');
                }

                if (empty($vraag1_antwoorden)) {
                        $this->setError('vraag1_antwoorden', 'Selecteer een antwoord a.u.b.');
                }

                if (empty($vraag2_antwoorden)) {
                        $this->setError('vraag2_antwoorden', 'Selecteer een antwoord a.u.b.');
                }

                if (empty($email)) {
                        $this->setError('email', 'Vul uw e-mail in');
                }

                /* No errors, insert in db
                else*/

                if(!$this->has_errors) {
                        if(($ret = $this->db->dbNewMessage($aanhef, $contactpersoon, $bedrijfsnaam, $email, $telefoon, $vraag1_antwoorden, $vraag2_antwoorden)) > '') {
                                //$json = array('result'         => 1);
                                if (SEND_EMAIL) {
                                        $this->sendEmail($aanhef,$contactpersoon,$bedrijfsnaam,$email,$telefoon,$vraag1_antwoorden,$vraag2_antwoorden);
                                        //This is for relocating to successful result page
                                        header('Location: result.php');
                                        exit;
                                } else {
                                        //This will need special treatment. You have to prepare an errorpage
                                        //for database-related issues.

                                        header("Location: database-error.html");
                                        exit;
                                }
                        }
                }
        }

        public function sendEmail($aanhef,$contactpersoon,$bedrijfsnaam,$email,$telefoon,$vraag1_antwoorden,$vraag2_antwoorden)
        {
        /* Just format the email text the way you want ... */
                $message_body   = "<div style=\"font-size:12px; font-weight:normal;\">Hallo,<br><br>"
                ."Het volgende bedrijf heeft zich zojuist aangemeld voor de Veiligheids Quiz:</div><br>"
                ."<table cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"1\" width=\"550px\"><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Bedrijfsnaam:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$bedrijfsnaam."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Aanhef:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$aanhef."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Contactpersoon:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$contactpersoon."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Telefoonnummer:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$telefoon."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">E-mail:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$email."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Antwoord vraag 1:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$vraag1_antwoorden."</td></tr><tr><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">Antwoord vraag 2:</td><td style=\"font-size:12px; color:#000000\">".$vraag2_antwoorden."</td></tr></table><br>";

                // Geef GELDIGE adressen op
                // Een korte benaming voor jouw website

                $website_naam = 'Aanmelding Quiz';
                // Jouw eigen geldige emailadres
                $eigen_emailadres = 'MY MAIL';
                // Een geldig emailadres voor errors
                $error_emailadres = 'MY MAIL';
                // De naam van de verzender
                $naam_verzender = ''.$bedrijfsnaam.'';
                // Het geldige emailadres van de afzender
                $email_verzender = ''.$email.'';
                // Een geldig emailadres of helemaal leeg laten
                $bcc_emailadres = '';
                // HTML mail? True/False
                $html = true;

                // De headers samenstellen
                $headers     = 'From: ' . $website_naam . ' <' . $eigen_emailadres . '>' . PHP_EOL;
                $headers    .= 'Reply-To: ' . $naam_verzender . ' <' . $email_verzender . '>' . PHP_EOL;
                $headers    .= 'Return-Path: Mail-Error <' . $error_emailadres . '>' . PHP_EOL;
                $headers    .= ($bcc_emailadres != '') ? 'Bcc: ' . $bcc_emailadres . PHP_EOL : '';
                $headers    .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
                $headers    .= 'X-Priority: Normal' . PHP_EOL;
                $headers    .= ($html) ? 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL : '';
                $headers    .= ($html) ? 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . PHP_EOL : '';

                mail(EMAIL_TO,MESSAGE_SUBJECT,$message_body,$headers);
        }

        public function setError($field, $errmsg)
        {
                $this->has_errors     = true;
                $this->errors[$field] = $errmsg;
        }

        public function errors($field)
        {
                if (array_key_exists($field,$this->errors)){
                        return $this->errors[$field];
                }

                return '';
        }
};
?>

<table width="675px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<form id="contact_form" method="post" action="">
<label class="label_aanhef" for="aanhef_1"><input name="aanhef" id="aanhef_1" type="radio" value="Dhr." /> Dhr.</label><label class="label_aanhef" for="aanhef_2"><input name="aanhef" id="aanhef_2" type="radio"  value="Mevr." /> Mevr.</label>
<span class="error"><?php echo $contact->errors('aanhef'); ?></span>

<input id="contactpersoon" name="contactpersoon" maxlength="120" type="text" onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"/><span class="error"><?php echo $contact->errors('contactpersoon'); ?></span>
<input id="bedrijfsnaam" name="bedrijfsnaam" maxlength="120" type="text" onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"/><span class="error"><?php echo $contact->errors('bedrijfsnaam'); ?></span>
<input id="email" name="email" maxlength="120" type="text" onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"/><span class="error"><?php echo $contact->errors('email'); ?></span>
<input id="telefoon" name="telefoon" maxlength="120" type="text" onFocus="window.scrollTo(0, 0);"/><span class="error"><?php echo $contact->errors('telefoon'); ?></span>


<label class="label_radio" for="vraag1_A"><input name="vraag1_antwoorden" id="vraag1_A" value="A. Dat is helaas fout, het goede antwoord is: C) < 1 Ohm" type="radio" />A) Geen eis</label>
<label class="label_radio" for="vraag1_B"><input name="vraag1_antwoorden" id="vraag1_B" value="B. Dat is helaas fout, het goede antwoord is: C) < 1 Ohm" type="radio"  />B) < 0,1 Ohm</label>
<label class="label_radio" for="vraag1_C"><input name="vraag1_antwoorden" id="vraag1_C" value="C. Gefeliciteerd dat is het goede antwoord." type="radio"  />C) < 1 Ohm</label>
<label class="label_radio" for="vraag1_D"><input name="vraag1_antwoorden" id="vraag1_D" value="D. Dat is helaas fout, het goede antwoord is: C) < 1 Ohm" type="radio" />D) < 10 Ohm</label>
<span id="vraag1_antwoorden" class="foutmelding_quiz">
<?php echo $contact->errors('vraag1_antwoorden'); ?>
</span>

<label class="label_radio" for="vraag2_A"><input name="vraag2_antwoorden" id="vraag2_A" value="A. Gefeliciteerd dat is het goede antwoord." type="radio" />A) Geen eis</label>
<label class="label_radio" for="vraag2_B"><input name="vraag2_antwoorden" id="vraag2_B" value="B. Dat is helaas fout, het goede antwoord is: A)  Geen eis" type="radio" />B) < 0,1 Ohm</label>
<label class="label_radio" for="vraag2_C"><input name="vraag2_antwoorden" id="vraag2_C" value="C. Dat is helaas fout, het goede antwoord is: A)  Geen eis" type="radio" />C) < 1 Ohm</label>
<label class="label_radio" for="vraag2_D"><input name="vraag2_antwoorden" id="vraag2_D" value="D. Dat is helaas fout, het goede antwoord is: A)  Geen eis" type="radio" />D) < 10 Ohm</label>
<span id="vraag2_antwoorden" class="foutmelding_quiz">
<?php echo $contact->errors('vraag2_antwoorden'); ?>
</span>
<input class="button submit" type="submit" value="" /><input id="newcontact" name="newcontact" type="hidden" value="1"></input>
</form>
```

Result.php

```
Aanhef: <?php echo $_POST["aanhef"]; ?><br />
Contactpersoon: <?php echo $_POST["contactpersoon"]; ?><br />
Bedrijfsnaam: <?php echo $_POST["bedrijfsnaam"]; ?><br />
Telefoon: <?php echo $_POST["telefoon"]; ?><br />
E-mail: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?><br />
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$contact` is getting set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace :

```
if(!empty($_POST['newcontact'])){
        $contact = new Contact();
} else{
        //header('Location: result.php');
}
```

By :

```
$contact = new Contact();
```

Cause if `$_POST['newcontact']` is empty, your `$contact` object is not set, and the `if(!empty($_POST['newcontact']))` is already in your `__construct()` of `Contact`

Add something like this to Contact to replace your redirect :

```
private $display_form = true;

public function getDisplayForm() {
    return $this->display_form;
}
```

And replace :

```
header('Location: result.php');
exit;
```

By :

```
$this->display_form = false;
```

And below, wrap your HTML like this :

```
<?php if ($contact->getDisplayForm()) { ?>

<!-- Your Form -->

<table width="675px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<form id="contact_form" method="post" action="">
...
</form>
</table>

<?php } else { ?>

<!-- Your Results -->

Aanhef: <?php echo $_POST["aanhef"]; ?><br />
Contactpersoon: <?php echo $_POST["contactpersoon"]; ?><br />
Bedrijfsnaam: <?php echo $_POST["bedrijfsnaam"]; ?><br />
Telefoon: <?php echo $_POST["telefoon"]; ?><br />
E-mail: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?><br /> 

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hee Fry! Thanks for the info, I fixed it, however can you help me howto show my data on result.php? I heard this can be done with a session? Only I don't know how exactly

Comment: I don't use redirect when I don't need to, so if I were you, instead of redirecting to result.php I'll set boolean to true or false to tell to the script below to display result or the regular form.

Comment: I just add the way I see it in my first answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(!empty($_POST['newcontact'])){
    $contact = new Contact();
 } else{
    //header('Location: result.php');
 }
```

Change it to

```
$contact = new Contact();
```

I mean to say : remove condition if() :

Its b'coz when page is not posted it will not create object of class Contact.

Due to this error comes.

Comment: Thanks, that works yes! Do you know how i can display the data on result.php when all fields have been filled?

Comment: You can use session and on result page display session data and on quiz page top clear session. Are you getting me ? or you can do one thing also. you can get last insert id and pass it on result.php page through GET. and you can fetch record from database and display on result page. You can choose either option. Please ask if you have any query.

Comment: Umm not really, I tried to follow the session explanation in this tutorial already but that did not helped me.. 
http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-order-form.html

Comment: Can you give me a starting example howto do this correctly Amrish?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that $contacts is actually filled? 
I see this statement at the beginning of the page:

```
if(!empty($_POST['newcontact'])){
        $contact = new Contact();
} else{
        //header('Location: result.php');
}
```

But no further checks if contacts is actually set. If the POST was empty contacts will be null. Check if contacts is null, and if it is, don't call methods or variables on it. :-)

Comment: Hee Annemarie, thanks for your reply, I found a solution for this. However, do you know how I can show the data on result.php?